# How to have multiple threads adding at the same Index of a texture without InterlockedAdd in a computeShader

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, compute-shader

[OperationToPerform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U84B.png)
I need to implement this operation where basically multiple threads have to add a quantity to the same index of a velocityField represented as a texture in a computeShader.

I used InterlockedAdd to do it, and because my quantites are float, i had to first convert it to int by multiplying it by a value like 1000 and then divide it again to reconvert it as a float.
It works fine but it makes the process a little bit heavy and i read that InterlockedAdd was a slow Operation. Is there any alternative to this ?
Thanks.